# Unable to set a large Image for LaunchScreen in swift spritekit

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, sprite-kit

Currently, I'm having a trouble with the LaunchScreen. I am trying to add a large  650 * 1134 size image to the launchScreen file. However, The image seems not to fit properly. In android I was able to fit in large images as background and set up the size and positions programmatically, but I find it difficult to do it ios since I'm new to it . I've googled but find answers that are ambiguous. It would be great if I can get a sample or hint from the pros here!

Comment: Not sure if this will make much difference, but the size you want is 640*1136, not 650 & 1134 as in your question. But this could well be a typo, and/or may not make a difference.

Answer (score 0):

You mast have a file called LaunchScreen.xib.
Choose your image go to assistant editor, go to size inspector and use the width and height you want.

Comment: Are there a example or a easy to understand tutorial other than apples doocuments?